# Stack of called functions ios

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

When I present UIViewController in my app called a lot of methods (please don't say me read UIViewController life circle), is there any way to get a list of called methods in xCode?

Comment: use NSLOG in all methods, from that u will know which method is called seeing log. You can even set break points in those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint in the `[YourViewController viewDidLoad]` method and then call stack will be shown within Xcode *Debug Navigator*:

[image]

(image taken from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debug_navigator/articles/about_debug_navigator.html)).

Answer (score 0):

And of course you can always use:

```
NSLog(@"call stack symbols: %@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
```