# Tapping outside a UITextField to stop editing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, tap

When I tap outside my `UITextField` to clear it's content and hide the keyboard it reacts as if I hit `return` and triggers actions associated with hitting `return`. It seems pretty counterintuitive  to me.

The textField cleared and keyboard dismissed I want, but not `amountEntered(_:)` called.. I want to be able to **abort** any action when I tap outside the `textField`

How can I change that?

[image]

All the code related to the `TextField`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    amountEnteredTextField.delegate = self

    registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    self.hideKeyboard()

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ scoreText: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}

@IBAction func amountEntered(_ sender: UITextField) {

    if allowNewAmount == true {

        if amountEnteredTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }

        amountLabel.text = amountEnteredTextField.text

        amountEnteredTextField.text = ""

    }
}
```

After debugging, the issue seems to be coming from this extension used to hide the keyboard:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func hideKeyboard() {

        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
       view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with tapping outside of the text field, clearing its content, or hiding the keyboard? The code you posted is not called when you tap outside of the text field.

Comment: @rmaddy This is the only code I have for the `textField` except for when I hit `return`

Comment: When you tap outside textfield, do you want to hide keyboard? or clear contents of textfield? or something else....

Comment: Both! Actually it does both already, but it thinks I hit `return` when I tap outside..

Comment: The code you posted is only called when you press Return in a text field. It is not called when you tap outside of a text field. No code is called when you tap outside of a text field unless you specifically added some code to deal with such taps.

Comment: @rmaddy I think I got it! Would the connection between the `TextField` and the code be the cause? It is connected as `Editing Did End` at the moment

Comment: The `textFieldShouldReturn` should not be connected to any event. It's a delegate method.

Comment: It is, I meant the connection to the function I thought would be called when `return` only is tapped

Comment: I dont see the code here but self.view.endEditing would cause the keyboard to dismiss when you tap outside of the textfield. IMHO, clearing the text field when you tap outside is bad design.

Comment: @martin oh man! there's so much missing in your question! add code! anything to do with the `textField` being cleared. there's absolutely no code sample even before your edit that shows the clearing part. and seriously... how is the animation going to help anyone help you?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I thought this would be more obvious to answer but it seems not, code added :)

Comment: @SonuVR I agree, but acting like hitting `return` is worse IMO!

Comment: @martin how is `amountEntered(_:)` connected? put a breakpoint here and check it's call trace in the debug navigator when you tap outside and maybe share that with us. also put a breakpoint in `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)` because all we see it does is resign any first responder.

Comment: So what is it exactly that you need ? The keyboard dismisses and the text field clears too. Isn't that what you want ? :)

Comment: @SonuVR Yes that I want :) But I don't want the `amountEntered ()` called.

Comment: @staticVoidMan `amountEntered(_:)` is connected to the `textField` with `Editing Did End`. What should I be looking for with the breakpoints?

Comment: @martin for the breakpoint, look at http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/ios/how-to-use-the-debug-area-and-debug-navigator-for-ios-app-development/

Comment: @staticVoidMan I don't know, that's the way I learned to do it in the Swift class. `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)` is not called when I tap outside the `textField`. For the rest tell me what info you need from the debugger.

Comment: @martin put a breakpoint in `amountEntered(_:)` then when it's called in the questionable event you have, go to the debug navigator. look at the call stack and share a screenshot of it

Comment: @martin also, what's in `hideKeyboard()`? and where all is it called from?

Comment: look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21045884/2857130) or [link](https://learnappmaking.com/debugging-fix-bugs-xcode-debugger-breakpoints/) for the stack trace debugging asked

Comment: @staticVoidMan Found the issue thanks to you and the debugger! It comes from `hideKeyboard` which calls `view.endEditing(true)` when it is dismissed! Don't know how to dismiss it without `view.endEditing(true)` tho!

Comment: @staticVoidMan Code added in the question

Comment: @martin Well.. you definitely have a mess on your hands with initial signs of code rot! address your design NOW! I would suggest something totally different from what you have.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I'm currently learning Swift and have no idea what to do here..

Comment: @martin well... you have written your code & you should know that you set a tap gesture on `self.view` that is linked to a method that does the `endEditing` part. This will ofcourse trigger `amountEntered` as it's set up to run when the `amountEnteredTextField` ends editing. now what you have here is, i dunno, probably what you wanted anyways. if not then what is your problem?

Comment: @staticVoidMan It wasn't a problem before. Can't I simply change `dismissKeyboard()` to dismiss the keyboard without `view.endEditing(true)`.

Comment: @martin well your set up is so. i see you mentioned `I want to be able to abort any action when I tap outside the textField`. with your current set up, it won't be so.

Comment: @martin what you could do instead is remove that `amountEntered` connection for `Editing Did End` and call `amountEntered` explicitly from inside `textFieldShouldReturn`. this way `amountEntered` will run only when user taps on return. try it. would this behavior better suit you?

Comment: @staticVoidMan It works great, thank you very much! I've been confused by delegates and "built-in methods" but I'm starting to get the point now!

Comment: @martin Well there you have it. I've posted an answer. Glad to have helped. Happy coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems your `amountEntered(_:)` is called anytime `amountEnteredTextField` ends editing. This is due to you setting it up as an `IBAction` for the event `.editingDidEnd`.

In `hideKeyboard()`, you have set up a tap gesture on `self.view` linked to `dismissKeyboard()` that does `view.endEditing(true)`.
This basically resigns any first responder; meaning `amountEnteredTextField` editing ends and hence `amountEntered(_:)` is called when you tap outside.

If you want to ensure `amountEntered(_:)` is called only when the user taps on the keyboard's return key then you should modify your design a little bit as so:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    /*
     Check to see which is the delegated textField.
     Basically to do textField-specific logic.
     Helps mostly if you have multiple textFields
     */
    if textField == amountEnteredTextField {
        amountEntered()
    }

    //resign textField
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func amountEntered() {
    if allowNewAmount, amountEnteredTextField.text != "" {
        amountLabel.text = amountEnteredTextField.text
        amountEnteredTextField.text = ""            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `view.endEditing(true)`in `Tap action responder`, this will call your `textFieldDidEndEditing:` delegate method. Instead of `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate of `UITextField`.